# why server shut down?

Tags: python, server

So I created a server but when I run it, it keeps shutting down. why it happens?

```
import socket

my_server = socket.socket()
my_server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8820))
my_server.listen()
```

on the other hand, when I add `accept()` function it doesn't shut down, but keeps running.
why can't it just be waiting for calls?

Answer (score 4):

[`socket.listen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) is non-blocking therefore the line although is executed, proceeds with the execution to the next line. There's nothing more to execute, so the program exits and shuts down the opened socket - the server dies.

You need to create a loop that will be blocking by expecting a data retrieval or any other blocking operation such as described in the [example section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example):

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:                 # the loop
            data = conn.recv(1024)  # the retrieval
            if not data: break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

The `listen()` function is only *configuration* step for the socket because a socket can listen but also do other operations such as only sending, or whatever you make it do. See the client program from the example section having no `accept()` anywhere hence not *awaiting* any connections to itself, only `connect()`-ing to already existing socket somewhere else:

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
```

Maybe [Client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) from Wikipedia will help understanding the general concept and the two-faced (or more, configuration thing) behavior of [a network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Also, unless you **need** to use the low-level socket, move away from it because there are just too many things you need to think about for making it at least usable not even secure. Instead, take a look at:

- [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) for more abstraction (not necessarily secure though)
- [secure(r) webservers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServers) + frameworks such as [Falcon](https://falconframework.org/), [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)